# Make global application menu replace titlebar in gnome-panel

Tags: unity, gnome-panel, appmenu

I am trying out Ubuntu 11.04, and one of my favourite features is the global application menu. I'm not a big fan of Unity, so I'm running the Classic Desktop. While the global application menu is here too, in Unity it replaces the titlebar when maximized, giving more screen space. Is it possible to have this functionality with gnome-panel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you want this

```
http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-10.10/webupd8-i386/gnome-window-applets_0.2.10-1~webupd8~maverick_i386.deb.html
```

if you experience applets moving unintentionally you should consider the complete lock down all panels option in

```
ubuntu tweak -> GNOME Settings -> complete lockdown of all panels
```

if you dont have ubuntu tweak you can get it at the software center...

Answer (score 1):

if you have compiz, you'll must go to "windows decoration" and wheres apear "any" add "& !state=maxhorz" or something like that. sorry the impressitions, but i'm not on my pc

Answer (score 1):

A very simple bash script to toggle the panel lock_down is:

```
#!/bin/bash
gconftool-2 --toggle /apps/panel/global/locked_down
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I don't seem to have problems with things moving around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes go to add to panel you will find four different indicators there choose the ones you want and just remove from panel anything you don't.
Note some widgets have to be unlocked first before you can remove them.

Comment: I meant how to make the global appmenu replace the titlebar in gnome-panel like in Unity.

Comment: I know that, this is the one you want it is the "indicator applet menu"